# Ubuntu 15.10 shutdown impossible

Tags: partitioning, shutdown

Unfortunately, I was not able to solve my problem in the meantime, so I'm asking this question again:

So I decided to turn my Laptop from Windwos 8.1 into a dualboot with Ubuntu and thus installed Ubuntu 15.10 through a memory stick. My goal was that I could choose between the OS I want everytime I start up.

After some initial expenditure I seemed to get the OS working fairly well, and thanks to GRUB I can choose the OS I want every time I boot.

However, the one huge issue I could not fix is Ubuntu simply wont shut down. Instead the screen just freezes, so I have to force shutdown everytime by pressing the button.

When starting up, I get an error named "Secure Boot Violation" Invalid signature detected. Check Secure Boot Policy in Setup.

After pressing ok the Laptop boots normally however.

I tried so far: changing GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" into GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force" --> Did not work.

I reinstalled Grub through Bootrepair and let it run through. ( /paste.ubuntu.com/15473378 )

--> Did not work either

Furthermore, I cannot reboot, I cannot sign out, I cannot log off, and I cannot shutdown by commandline (tried sudo -shutdown -h now) it all results into freezing

Now before I mess up too much I wanted to ask you guys for help.

I am using a MSI MS-16H2 Notebook

Where I suspect the error might be situated in:

Gparted does always give me an error message when I run it, first:

"The Argument is invalid, while /dev/sda was positioned for reading."

When I click ignore, I get another error called:

"The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used."

--> After clicking ok. I can use Gparted normally.

After I ran boot-repair, I was told that I should make sure that the boot-partition is located in /dev/sdc

--> Now here I think where the error is.

Because I find a BOOT-Partition (fat32, /boot/efi) in:

/dev/mapper/isw/dddegaaaac_RAID0IMSVolume2

And then I find the BIOS_RVY Partition in /dev/sdc

(where I was told the boot-partition must be)

Do you guys think this might be the error? And if not, what else might I have to consider so that my Notebook will finally shut down? Furthermore, if I change the Location of the Boot-Partition now, could this harm the Windows-OS?

--> If someone could tell me how I can rename this Raid's horrible name I'd be quite happy too.

Also, there are 2 Disks à 119 GB (/dev/sda and /dev/sdb) which are labelled "not assigned" --> I think this is where the initial error message in Gparted comes from. Can I use them or may I not change them because they contain some curcial windows-data or something?

I posted the Images of Gparted and the Link after boot-repair to make it more clear.

[Gpated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70sxK.jpg)
[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp9pB.jpg)

Thanks alot for dealing with my issues.

Comment: Not an answer, but `sudo init 6` or `left ALT + SysRq + R` ought to do a reboot. Use `sudo init 0` for shutdown.

Comment: @Rabbit When you installed Ubuntu, have you disabled *secure boot* in UEFI settings (it seems not because you get a secure boot violation error)?

Comment: Hey, I aready disabled secure boot at an earlier stage (so the secure boot violation error does no longer appear). I used your command "sudo init 0" and this was actually the first command which really shut the computer down! sudo init 6 did cause the expected freeze however, so I was not able to reboot but to shutdown. The shutdown was quite abrupt though so I think I should not use this command too often. Next im trying to reinstall my boot-partition to /dev/sdc by using Gparted-Live from USB. Thanks alot for your help and further suggestions, ill keep you updated.